# Error en backbone javascript: A "url" property or function must be specified

Tags: javascript, backbone

Estoy realizando un diseño por mvc en backbone JavaScript, pero al implementar la función para eliminar un elemento de la colección me visualiza este error:

> ```
> A "url" property or function must be specified
> ```

Este es el código:

```
eliminarCliente: function(idCliente) {

  var cliente = this.clientes.findWhere({      
    id: idCliente
  });

  if(cliente){
    cliente.destroy();
    this.clientes.remove(cliente);

    router.navigate('listarClientes', {
      trigger: true
    });

  }
}
```

Captura

[image: Figura]

Answer (score 0):

El problema lo tienes seguramente en esta línea:

```
cliente.destroy();
```

El método `destroy` lo que hace es, mediante [Backbone.sync](http://backbonejs.org/#Sync), intentar destruir ese modelo en el servidor mediante una petición `DELETE`, devolviéndote el objeto `XMLHttpRequest` de esa petición o `false` si el objeto al que hace referencia ese modelo no está guardado todavía en el servidor.

Si estás usando una `API Rest` para actualizar tus datos en el servidor, añade la `URL` al modelo para que `Backbone` sepa dónde actualizar esos datos (en este parámetro se espera o la representación `String` de una `URL` o una función):

```
var miModelo = Backbone.Model.extend({
    url: "/url/a/la/api/rest/"
});
```

Si por el contrario no está usando una `API Rest` y los datos los estás guardando localmente (usando [localStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage) o [sessionStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Window/sessionStorage)) sin usar un adaptador como [Backbone.localStorage](https://github.com/jeromegn/Backbone.localStorage), entonces intenta hacer un *override* del parámetro [sync](http://backbonejs.org/#Model-sync) para reescribir cada método [CRUD](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/CRUD) con tu propia implementación:

> Si lees la entrada de `Backbone.sync`, podrás consultar cada uno de los parámetros que recibe `sync`:
>
> - metodo: será el que contenga la representación string del método CRUD
> - modelo: vendrá el modelo que quieres guardar, borrar, actualizar, etc....
> - opciones: (parámetro opcional) es donde vendrán contenidas las callbacks de success y error

```
var miModelo = Backbone.Model.extend({

    sync: function(metodo, modelo, opciones) {

        switch (metodo) {

            case "create":
            break;

            case "read":
            break;

            case "update":
            break;

            case "delete":
            break;

        }

    }

});
```